# Use SQL query result column names as pandas dataframe column names

Tags: python, sql, pandas, pymssql

How can I add the columns names from sql query to pandas dataframe. I'm doing the following, but `columns=columns` doesn't work in my case.

```
import pymssql
import pandas as pd


con = pymssql.connect(
     server="MSSQLSERVER",
     port="1433",
     user="us",
     password="pass",
     database="loc")

cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT id from ide")

data=cur.fetchall()

pandas=pd.DataFrame(data)

cur.close()
con.close()
```

So when I print "pandas" it turns out to be without headers. So how can I receive them?

Comment: Look into `read_sql_table`: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_sql_table.html#pandas.read_sql_table

Comment: hey guys, read sql dont work in my case-please other suggestions

Comment: I have added a comment let me know if it worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First establish the connection: I saw you used MSSQL

```
import pyodbc
# Parameters
server = 'server_name'
db = 'db_name'

# Create the connection
conn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=' + server + ';DATABASE=' + db + ';Trusted_Connection=yes')
```

Then use pandas:

```
df = pandas.read_sql(sql, conn)
```

Answer (score 12):

I've also found adding as_dict=True to the cursor object works:

```
cur = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)
```

Then you can run the rest as you have it:

```
cur.execute("SELECT id from ide")
data=cur.fetchall()
pandas=pd.DataFrame(data)
```

and pandas will grab the column names from the dictionary

Comment: Which one is better? pymssql or pyodbc? Using pyodbc, I found a lot of difficulty when using it through AWS Lambda.

Comment: pymssql works well now